# What is the best way to create RAID 1?

Tags: centos, raid, software-raid, raid-1

I'm looking for a way to create the RAID 1 array without losing my data on CentOS. Here's my situation: I've got a web server running on CentOS. There is one VG partition with few LV volumes. I bought a second HDD (the same model and size as the first one) and I want to create the RAID 1 configuration. I can't just shut down this server for more than an hour because my clients will be disappointed. I need to do this as quickly as possible with minimal risk of data loss.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Im afraid you cannot add mirror without rebooting.

New mirror has to be to be synchronized first. I think that operation cannot be done when system is running and it will be done while rebooting. It may take long time to synchronize if you have a lot of data there.

Here is howto: [Adding a mirror to an existing LVM volume (proxmox)](http://lawrit.lawr.ucdavis.edu/itdocs/it/how-to/adding-a-mirror-to-an-existing-lvm-volume-proxmox/view)

I never had problem with manipulating lvms, but I **highly recommend to make full backup** before operation.

Edit:

Well, if you really, really don't want to reboot - you can use chroot and dismount root partition. When volumes are not mounted - you probably will be able to resync them, but... if you have some services (database, web server, mail server) and if they need that disk - it doesn't change much for your scenario and these services must be "down" for some time.

Just inform your users about 1 hour maintenance at night or something like that.

Comment: Quick update, you can do it without rebooting, but... See the edit.

Comment: Indeed, unfortunately I do have mysql, http and mail servers on that machine. Anyway thank you for advice. I'm going to do this tonight.